# samba share not auto mounting at boot

Tags: boot, samba, automount, fstab

Well it was working fine, but I removed hidden config files from my $HOME and now mounting halts at boot. I have to solve it manually or skip to get my gdm. What could be wrong, can anyone tell me ? Thanks in advance.

P.S. After I login, I have to run `sudo mount -a` to get the mounted samba share which used to auto mount before I removed the hidden configuration from my $HOME directory.

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=50931261-ec36-47dc-b557-3f6d761e09b1 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda5 during installation
# Commented out by Dropbox
# UUID=5974aeb8-2f01-47d0-8e79-7295b72604ea /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=16b54e62-6be8-4c3e-aab5-693c6e6778d9 none            swap    sw              0       0
//192.168.1.2/public /home/sagar/Public cifs rw,guest,_netdev 0 0
UUID=5974aeb8-2f01-47d0-8e79-7295b72604ea /home ext4 defaults,user_xattr 0 2
```

Basically the samba share is read/write access with public share

Comment: Can you paste into your question the contents of /etc/fstab, please?  (Make sure to remove any passwords if you set them up manually in that file).  It's most likely your credentials file that you removed - are your shares password protected?

Comment: @Scaine Done, the share is a public share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that the root issue is that something is not ready to support CIFS when the CIFS mount is called from the init script, but is by the time you get a login prompt.  You could try to track that down and update your init script order, OR...

If you are not using anything from //192.168.1.2/public until the system is up, then I would suggest changing from a boot-time mount to an automount.  That way it won't be mounted until you actually access it, by which time everything should be up.  The [Autofs Ubuntu Community Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs) gives more info on how to set it up.

I actually use autofs for the exact same purpose (but with more drives) on my network at home.

Comment: I am still confused on samba configuration of autofs especially the guest credential for username and password. Yet I am going to accept this answer as this seems to solve the problem if I get the configuration right.

Comment: Here are a couple of pages that may help with the particulars of handling the smb (or cifs) credentials: http://www.knoppmythwiki.org/index.php?page=Autofs+and+samba and http://www.howtoforge.com/accessing_windows_or_samba_shares_using_autofs .